# A regex to match a string that is surrounded by %

Tags: regex, string, split

i need a regex to find all string that is surrounded by %

example:

> A=%Test1% OR B = %Test2% AND (C=%Test3
>   OR C = %Test4)

what i need are the strings:

> %Test1%, %Test2%, %Test3% and %Test4%

thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `%Test3 OR C = %`? `%Test4` is not *surrounded* by `%`, so either your specification is lacking or your input is.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can easily test regexes online using sites like http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
%[^%]+%
```

Which matches a percent sign, followed by a non-zero number of non-percent characters and another percent.

Comment: What if the string would be like: A = '5%' and B = '6%' ?

Comment: sorry, i forgot the closing % in(C=%Test3% OR C = %Test4%)  ... thans joey! it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `%[[:alnum::]+%` would do the job?