# A regex to match Strings contained after ":"

Tags: java, regex

I need to use scan.useDelimiter() to recognize Strings taking place after ":".

I am making a Scanner that takes the following line from a list of similar entries.

```
c : 20002 : The Dragon :     Dreama : 10000 :   1 :  22 :   9 :  237.20 :   60.47 :  354.56
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    public Boolean readFile (){ //Fix tomorrow
    while ( input.hasNext () ) {
        char x =                stat.next().charAt(0);
        String line =           input.nextLine().trim();
        Scanner stat =          new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*")

        if( line.length()== 0 || input.next().charAt(0) == '/' ) continue;
        switch ( x ) {
            case 'c' :
                int a =         stat.nextInt();
                String b =      stat.next();
                break;
            case 't' :
                //...
```

For some reason I cannot get this to Scan correctly. For the entry above I need the following strings.

```
20002, The Dragon, Dreama, 10000, etc.
```

As you can see I need the spaces at the edges of the phrases ignored, but if there is a space in between a phrase such as "The Dragon" it needs preserved.

The following questions did not help me out:
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814469/a-regex-to-match-a-string-that-is-surrounded-by) / 
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079243/regular-expression-global-search-between-2-whole-words)

Comment: `char x = stat.next().charAt(0);` doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: The first char in the record indicates what type of object to build. I am using it for a case statement for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()`, but `.useDelimiter()` does the same job (only with a different output).

What you need is to first get the char and then proceed to the rest. Maybe this will give you a clue:

```
public Boolean readFile (){ //Fix tomorrow
    while( input.hasNext () ) {
       char x =           input.next().charAt(0); // get the char
       System.out.println("char obtained: "+x);

       String line =      input.nextLine().trim();
       Scanner stat =     new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*")

       while ( stat.hasNext() ) {
          if (stat.hasNext("")||stat.hasNext(Pattern.compile("/.*"))) continue;
          // above line is equivalent to:
          // if( token.length()== 0 || token.charAt(0) == '/' ) continue;
          // but is better because does not consume a token
          switch ( x ) {
              case 'c' :
                  int a =         stat.nextInt(); // 20002
                  String b =      stat.next(); // "The Dragon"
                  System.out.println("b obtained: "+b);
                  // some options here:
                  // - add a line for each expected var like:
                  String b2 =      stat.next(); // "Dreama"
                  String i =      stat.nextInt(); // 10000
                  String j =      stat.nextInt(); // 1
                  // ...

                  // OR: - iterate through the remaining tokens and do something
                  // while (stat.hasNext()) { System.out.println(stat.next()); }

                  // OR: - get an array of the remaining tokens using split():
                  // String[] restOfLine = stat.nextLine().split("\\s*:\\s*");
                  break;
              case 't' :
                  //...
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String line = input.nextLine().trim();
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");
```

Note that I am just reusing the regex in your question. Your regex will strip out all the redundant leading and trailing spaces in each of the tokens. The `trim()` on the whole input is still needed to remove the leading and trailing spaces, which the regex in the `split()` method does not match and will not touch.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

So you will end up having -

```
while ( input.hasNext () ) {
    char x =                input.next().charAt(0);
    String[] words =           input.nextLine().split(":");
    for(String s : words){
        s.trim();
    }
    ....
```

Also, Im dont think you need to get your first char. I havent seen your code, so I dont know. Maybe you are using it later, but it seems extraneous to me.

Comment: Thank you, this looks way more elegant than what I was planning to do. I have one question, will this work even though the String at the end of the entry does not have ":" after it?

Comment: @Dustin Yes, it will work just fine. The last element of the array will be (after trimming) 354.56

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the Scanner as you should: you have to iterate over the found tokens:

```java
String line = "c : 20002 : The Dragon :     Dreama : 10000 :   1 :  22 :   9 :  237.20 :   60.47 :  354.56";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String token = scanner.next();
    // do you stuff with the token 
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

This prints:

```
c
20002
The Dragon
Dreama
10000
1
22
9
237.20
60.47
354.56
```

Which seems to be what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why people are suggesting `split()`, since `useDelimiter()` does the exact same job and the question says ***I need to use `scan.useDelimiter()` to recognize Strings taking place after ":".*** If `useDelimiter()` does not solve, `split()` certainly wont.

Comment: @acdcjunior split() is a good suggestion because there are many ways to skin a cat. Its a safe bet that Dustin doesnt *need* to use useDelimiter(), so why not suggest a cleaner option?

Comment: @Dgrin91 Some reasons off the top of my head: (1) because he asked for `useDelimiter()`; (2) because he has a stopping/continue condition `if( line.length()== 0 || input.next().charAt(0) == '/' ) continue;` that must mean something; (3) because the approaches are pretty much equivalent, and if he didnt achieve it with one, maybe the problem is somewhere else, changing it all may end up at the same barrier.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

To use a regex to match the `:` delimited strings you could use this expression which also filters the spaces surrounding the delimiters

`(?::)\s*([^:]*)\s*(?=:|$)`

[image]

## Java Code Example

In this example you'll be interested in values collected from capture group 1

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "c : 20002 : The Dragon :     Dreama : 10000 :   1 :  22 :   9 :  237.20 :   60.47 :  354.56";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(?::)\\s*([^:]*)\\s*(?=:|$)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

Yields

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => : 20002 
            [1] => : The Dragon 
            [2] => :     Dreama 
            [3] => : 10000 
            [4] => :   1 
            [5] => :  22 
            [6] => :   9 
            [7] => :  237.20 
            [8] => :   60.47 
            [9] => :  354.56
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20002 
            [1] => The Dragon 
            [2] => Dreama 
            [3] => 10000 
            [4] => 1 
            [5] => 22 
            [6] => 9 
            [7] => 237.20 
            [8] => 60.47 
            [9] => 354.56
        )

)
```